# GraphQL Query unable to feed server current timestamp while Querying Strapi API

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, strapi

**My GraphQL query:**

```
polls(where: {PublishedOn_lte: 1601378961978, enabled_ne: false}, sort: "PublishedOn:DESC", 
limit: 10, start: 0)
```

I want to feed in a value for the **PublishedOn_lte:**  field so that the current datetime value or timestamp gets inserted before the query in executed. Went through entire Strapi docs but could not find a solution.